# PyQT arguments error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I'm still fairly new to coding and Python and have an arguments error with running one of my classes. But i'm not sure what it means or where I'm going wrong. So the error it's giving me is: error is `Type:Error __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Here is the code:

```
import os, sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class mainUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
                super(mainUI, self).__init__()
                self.mainUI()

        def mainUI(self):

                self.showFullScreen()
                self.setWindowTitle('TimeBot')

                palette = QPalette()
                palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush (QPixmap ("Resources/bg1.jpg")))
                self.setPalette(palette)

                qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
                qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)
                qbtn.move(5,5)
                self.button = qbtn             
                qbtn.show()

class labelTest(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent):
                super(labelTest, self).__init__(parent)

                lbl = QtGui.QLabel("This is a test", self)
                lbl.move(50, 50)

                self.show()

def main():
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

        env = mainUI()
        labels = labelTest()   

        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `show` a `QPushButton`. (Well, if you don't want it to appear in an own window.)

You need need to set a layout for your window an add this button (and the label) to this layout.

```
class mainUI(QtGui.QDialog):
```

The QMainWindow has a layout set already. (I think, please correct me if I'm wrong.)

```
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(mainUI, self).__init__()
       self.mainUI()
       self.show()
```

This is important (it shows the window).

```
   def mainUI(self):
       layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
```

This creates a layout; you may also want to use QHBoxLayout.
           ...
           # no moving (because there's a layout)
           # no qbtn.show() (This would create a new window.)
           layout.addWidget(qbtn)
This puts the button into the layout.
           self.setLayout(layout)
This sets the layout of the window to our newly created and filled layout.

```
class labelTest(QtGui.QLabel):
```

This should be a label, doesn't it?

```
   def __init__(self, parent):
      super(labelTest, self).__init__("This is a test",parent)
      # no new QLabel
      # no moving (because there's a layout)
      ...
      # no self.show() (since we don't want to create a new window)

def main():
   ...
   env.layout().addWidget(labelTest())
```

This creates a new labelTest and adds it to the current layout of env.

```
   ...
```

If you want to read a bit I would recommend [the PySide documentation](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/index.html). This is a different Qt binding for Python but the API is quite the similar.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the `parent` argument when you create your label. `labels = labelTest()`

A common practice( as far as I've seen), is to set the parent argument with a default to `None`

```
class labelTest(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
```

The error message tells you that a function `(__init__)` expected two arguments `(self, parent)`, but only got one. The one argument it got, was `self` which is passed automagically to every class function.

Edit:

To show it in the main window, you need to add the main window as the parent.
`labels = labelTest(env)`

And you have to edit the labelTest class a bit to move the widget, not the label itself.

```
class labelTest(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent):
                super(labelTest, self).__init__(parent)

                lbl = QtGui.QLabel("This is a test", self)
                self.move(50, 50)

                self.show()
```

Comment: That sort of worked... It now opens the label in a new window, which I don't want.

Comment: Where do you want it then?

Comment: I want it to show in the main window, but only when I call it.